# Get Regex.Matches to start the match at Position 0

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use Regex to count the number of times a certain string appears in another comma-separated string.

I am using `Regex.Matches(comma-separated string, certain string).Count` to grab the number. The only issue I have is that I want it to simply count as a match if it lines up at the start of the string.

For instance, if I have the comma separated string

```
string comma_separated = "dog,cat,bird,blackdog,dog(1)";
```

and want to see how many times the search string matches with the contents of the comma-separated string

```
string search = "dog";
```

I use:

```
int count = Regex.Matches(comma_separated, search).Count;
```

I would expect it to be 2 since it matches up with

"**dog**,cat,bird,blackdog,**dog**(1)",

however it returns a 3 since it is also matching up with the dog part of blackdog.

Is there any way I can get it to only count as a match when it recognizes a match starting at the start of the string? Or am I just using Regex incorrectly?

Comment: Regex seems like the wrong tool for the job here. You could split the string on commas, and then filter the results by ones that start with "dog" and then count the number of occurrences.

Comment: @zzzzBov yea I was wondering that, thanks!

Comment: What about something like `[^,]dog`? - Either start of line or comma preceding the word dog?

Comment: @zzzzBov the problem with that approach is it also counts the string  "doggggg"

Comment: @Kishore, and given the details of the question, that sounds appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, a regex may not be the most logical way for you to achieve your desired result. However, if you would like to use a regex to find your matches, something like this would provide your desired result

```
(?<=,|^)dog
```

This will perform a "positive lookbehind" to ensure that the word "dog" is preceded by either a comma or is at the start of the string you are searching.

More info available on lookarounds in Regex here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 1):

```
  string comma_separated = "dog,cat,bird,blackdog,dog(1)";
  int count = Regex.Matches(comma_separated, string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", Regex.Escape("dog")), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count;
```

By appending the **\b** to either side of the text you can find the "EXACT" match within the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this pattern: `search = @"\bdog";`. `\b` matches word boundary.